# Chat bubble grouping by time wise

Tags: javascript, node.js

im trying to make a chat application with node.js I want to enclose sevaral messages within 10 seconds inside the one div(bubble) like facebook and gmail chat. follows the code of mine.

```
var last_date= Date.now(); 

var cre_div = "<div class='row message'>new</div>";

function addMessage(msg, pseudo, date, self) {


    Date.now = function() { return new Date().getTime(); }

    if(self){
        if( last_date!=null && last_date+10000<Date.now()) {

            var chat =  $("#chatEntries").append('<div class="row message"><p class="infos"><span class="pseudo">'+pseudo+'</span><time class="date" title="'+Date.now()+'">'+Date.now()+'</time></p><p>' + msg + '</p></div>');
            console.log(chat);

                //$("#chatEntries").append(cre_div);

                last_date=Date.now();
            }


        $("#chatEntries").append('<div class="row message self"><p class="infos"><span class="pseudo">'+pseudo+'</span></p><p>' + msg + '</p></div>');
        //$("#chatEntries").append(cre_div);
        last_date=Date.now();
    }

    else {

        $("#chatEntries").append('<div class="row message"><p class="infos"><span class="pseudo">'+pseudo+'</span></p><p>' + msg + '</p></div>');

        //$("#chatEntries").document.createElement('cre_div');
        last_date=Date.now();
    }

    time();

}
```

Comment: what is your question ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was kinda interesting to me to try that and i actualy change your code a lot  hope you get the idea, so there you go

```
Date.now = function () {
    return new Date().getTime();
}

var last_group = {
    me: false,
    time:Date.now()
}
var messages_count = 0;

function addMessage(msg, pseudo, date, me) {
    messages_count++;

    if(messages_count < 1){
        console.log('first message');
        createGroup(msg, pseudo, date, me);
        last_group.me = me;
    } else {

        if(last_group.me == me){
            if(last_group.time + 10000 > Date.now()) {
                 //console.log('adding to last group');                
                 addToGroup(msg, pseudo, date, me);                
            } else {                
                //console.log('creating new group', last_group.me, me);
                createGroup(msg, pseudo, date, me);
            }

        } else {

            //console.log('creating new group', last_group.me, me);
            createGroup(msg, pseudo, date, me);

        }   
    }
}

function addToGroup(msg, pseudo, date, me){
    $("#group-" + last_group.time).append('<div class="row message' + (me ? ' self' : '') + '">' + pseudo + '<p>' + msg + '</p></div>');
}

function createGroup(msg, pseudo, date, me){
    last_group.time = Date.now();
    var html = '<div class="group" id="group-' + last_group.time + '"><div class="row message' + (me ? ' self' : '') + '">' + pseudo + ' - ' + Date.now() + '<p>' + msg + '</p></div></div><br>';
    //console.log(html);
    $("#chatEntries").append(html);            
    last_group.me = me;
}

setInterval(function () {
    addMessage('Hello', 'pseudo', new Date().getTime(), true);
}, 1000);

setInterval(function () {
    addMessage('Hello 2', 'pseudo 2', new Date().getTime(), false);
}, 5000);
```

jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/putd7e0t/4/)

Comment: useful but i want go group separate users(pseudo) also

Comment: Then update your question, you didn't mention that. To do what you want you simply change `me` in `last_group` to `user` and if the new message's user is not same then create new group and add `last_group.user = 'username'`. That's pretty simple. How about you try yourself first.